# delete the records based on condition from array

Tags: javascript

```
resp = {
            "result": [
                {
                    "name": "john",
                    "value": "he has car"
                },
                {
                    "name": "may",
                    "value": "she has phone"
                },
                {
                    "name": "john",
                    "value": "he has car"
                },
                {
                    "name": "may",
                    "value": "she has phone"
                }
            ]
        };
```

result :

```
 for(i=0; i<resp.result.length;i++){
        if (resp.result[i].name === "may" && resp.result[i].value.startsWith("she")) {
            resp.result[i].splice(resp.result.indexOf(resp.result[i].value) - 1, 2);
            i--;
        }
    }
```

once "if" condition satisfied, splicing first 2 records from array. then unable to iterate the rest of the records.
but there is still records exists which has to satisfy "if" the condition.

Comment: tried decrementing the index value, no effect

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply use `Array#filter` ? Because the way you're handling splice seems complicated and looks *wrong* (specifically the `.splice(..., 2)` where two is the number of elements you wish to delete)

```js
const resp = {
  "result": [{
      "name": "john",
      "value": "he has car"
    },
    {
      "name": "may",
      "value": "she has phone"
    },
    {
      "name": "john",
      "value": "he has car"
    },
    {
      "name": "may",
      "value": "she has phone"
    }
  ]
};

resp.result = resp.result.filter(({name, value})=>{
  return !(name === "may" && value.startsWith("she"))
});

console.log(
  resp.result
);
```

Comment: this code will delete oly first 2 records, actual result should be empty array, i mean 3rd 4th record (index 2,3) should also get delete. coz on 4th iteration "if" condition will satisfy

Comment: @chandu could you provide an example with the output you're expecting?

Comment: result array should be an empty

Comment: @chandu your if condition (if correct) will only *filter* values if the name is **may** and that the value starts with **she**. Your object *john* does not resolve to true for that condition. Could you clarify how the list is supposed to be empty with your condition?

Comment: based on my if condition, 2 records will filter right ? ie. 2nd 4th record. on my first condition true, i will splice 2 records, so 3rd and 4th record will remain in array. 3rd and 4th record will come into 0,1 index position in the array. am i right ? as per the loop it will continue to find 3rd index position, which is not exists. so i am decrement the index value to loop from 0.

Answer (score 0):

creating a function to remove an item from array and then shift the rest of the array,

```
removeArrayElement = function(callback) {
var i = this.length;
while (i--) {
    if (callback(this[i], i)) {
        this.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
};
```

now you can use it like this,

```
resp = [ {num:1, str:"a"}, {num:2, str:"b"}, {num:3, str:"c"} ];
resp.removeArrayElement( function(item, idx) {
    return item.str == "c";
});
```